# vscode: How to search in installed package?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I want to search in the go pkg go-git.

ctrl+shift+f searches only in my module.

[image: how-to-search-in-installed-package]

Comment: you can click the 3 dots in the search pane for advanced search and provide a path to search in.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this will not directly answer, but it's an workaround, that I personally prefer:

Hovering over a function, that is from a foreign package, VS Code shows the godoc description. There is always a link to [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5#PlainCloneContext) (This link is for the `PlainClone` example):

[image: VS CODE Hovering]

Following it you are redirected directly to GO's package website.
Here is already a nice list with the module's functions.

if you want to dive deeper:
On the top of the repository there is the link to the repo host.

[image: go pkg website]

Experiences show, that this is mostly Github. While GitHub's search used to be proscribed, it can nowadays be a mightful tool:

https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories

Again I mention that is very subjective, but GO's complex way of storing modules locally with it's many env variables and stuff made me feel using the internet is more comfortable =)